Google Play review claims to not see our website hosting a simple Privacy Policy page
Could not find anyone else that has had this exact problem, so hoping someone has a clue what is going on or what to check. Pulling out my little remaining hair on this one.
We have been trying to get a free app published for weeks. Even though it collects no data, all apps are now required to have a Privacy Policy page for the Play Store.
For reasons unknown when the Google reviewers check our site, it is not visible to them. The response is as if the entire website does not exist.
To reduce costs we are using share hosting at Ionis, with their free 256 bit SSL certificate. The last DNS setting changes were made over a week ago when we shifted it from a virtual private server to basic shared hosting.
The page is at http://iscanthings.com/privacy and works fine for us. When we check it via geopeeker.com it appears to be showing in other countries.
The last response to an appeal to Play Store was "In regards to your question, at this time, I'm not able to comment on this matter" (we were simply asking them to try and resolve the IP address for our domain to give us some clue).
Can anybody suggest what could be causing them to not see the website? If anyone cannot see the site/page for any reason that would be a start.
Actual screen shot provided by Google Play below.

